# How to add columns in multiple lists?

Tags: python

In python,

```
y = [1,2,3,4]
    [1,2,3,4]
    [1,2,3,4]
    [1,2,3,4]
```

Notice that `y` contains four lines of lists, and it is not a matrix.
What I am trying to do is to add last columns of fours and output:

```
[1,2,3,16]
```

Comment: there is no such collection in python..

Comment: You have a syntax error.  What is `y`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I opened a text file and did readline() and split() to define y and that is what i have in y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us suppose that you have list of lists:

```
y = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

res = y[0][:3] + [sum(el[3] for el in y)]
print res

>>> [1, 2, 3, 16]
```

Comment: does this mean i need to convert y into list of lists first?

Comment: When you read and split content of file you will get a list of lines, just iterate over this list now, convert strings into lists and split